# Find the longest string in a binary string tree python

Tags: python, string, binary-tree

Alright so I need to define a recursive function longest_length() that takes a binary string tree and returns the length of the longest string in the tree.

I admittedly have no clue how to do this, but this is what I have set up:

```
def add_leaves(bnt):
    """Takes a BNT and returns the length of the largest string in the tree.

    BNT - number"""
    if isinstance(bnt, str):
        return bnt
    else:
        return ????
```

can anyone help me out? this isn't really homework, just a question I came upon while studying for finals that I feel I should know how to answer

Comment: How does the BNT look like? Please give an example input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a tree node class that has a string value attribute, and attributes to store its left and right children, the implementation would be fairly simple:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def find_max(node):
    if (node is None): return ""
    return max([find_max(node.left), node.val, find_max(node.right)], key=len)

tree = TreeNode("test", TreeNode("asdasjkdnaskdjasd", TreeNode("")), TreeNode("a"))
print find_max(tree) # asdasjkdnaskdjasd
```

You can see a demo here: http://ideone.com/SE39tM